Programmatically add label with URL
I am currently adding a label with URL called UAT Template based on the dropdown item select. The label should not be created if it already exists.
The issues are:

The link is not opened in the new tab
The label is not created for some reason

function AddURL() {
  let lblTemplate = document.getElementsByClassName("ard-FormField-description")[8];
  
  //Check if the lblTemplate contain word 'UAT Template location'
  if (lblTemplate.innerHTML !== '' && lblTemplate.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf('UAT Template Location') > -1) {
    if (lblTemplate.indexOf(lblTemplate) == -1) {
      // create anchor link element
      let link = document.createElement("a")

      // Create txt
      let txt = document.createTextNode("UAT Template Location")

      //append txt to anchor element
      link.appendChild(txt)

      // set the title
      link.title = " Click to UAT Template Location";

      // set the href property
      link.href = "https://gampoendev.com/:w:/r/teams/teamcollab/Shared%20Documents/Templates/";
      link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');

      // get text to add link to

      lblTemplate.appendChild(link)
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }
}


Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem that you are trying to solve. Additional details — including all relevant code, error messages, and debugging logs — will help readers to better understand your problem and [what you are asking].

What is this? lblTemplate.indexOf(lblTemplate) are you testing if an array contains itself? Also I see no code that creates label

Please include your HTML code, but even without that, I can already tell you that you're on the wrong track: it's absolutely not recommended to search for a string in .innerHTML or to use static array indexes to retrieve a specific element. You're getting ready to create unstable code with a lot of technical debt.

else {       return;     } is also unnecessary.

remove the two conditions and add one for both
if (lblTemplate && lblTemplate.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf('uat template location') === -1) {
}

use the following for the target
link.target = "_blank";

Like this
function AddURL() {
  let lblTemplate = document.getElementsByClassName("ard-FormField-description")[8];
  if (lblTemplate && lblTemplate.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf('uat template location') === -1) {
    let link = document.createElement("a");
    let txt = document.createTextNode("UAT Template Location");
    link.appendChild(txt);
    link.title = "Click to UAT Template Location";
    link.href = "https://gampoendev.com/:w:/r/teams/teamcollab/Shared%20Documents/Templates/";

    // use the following for setting the target
    link.target = "_blank";
    lblTemplate.appendChild(link);
  } 
}

